# C# StackTrace for referenced projects from unit test

Tags: c#, stack-trace

For a project I need to know how many methods are called at the end of a unit test. (Or something like a call hierarchy in Visual Studio (not at runtime). I've created a test project for this. But I only get the methods back that are called within the unit test project.

So for example I have a class library with the following class (assembly):

```
public  class Program
{
    public void A()
    {
        B();
        C();
    }

    public void B()
    {

    }

    public void C()
    {
        B();
        D();
    }

    public void D()
    {

    }
}
```

And a unit test (assembly) with the following test methods

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
        new Program().A();
        int count = stackTrace.FrameCount;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod2()
    {
        StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
        new Program().C();
        int count = stackTrace.FrameCount;
    }
```

In both unit tests count = 12. When I inspect the properties of stackTrace variable I see only methods called of the unit test assembly. Is there a way to include the calls of the class library assembly in the stackTrace?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Constructing a stack trace object will get the stack trace of the code that constructed it, it will not gather the stack trace of the code following it. Which means that in your test methods, you get the stack trace leading up to the construction of the stack trace object on the first line of each test method, the rest of the method has no impact on this stack trace.

Comment: But when I placed the construction of the StackTrace to the end of the testmethod the results are still the same...

Comment: Yes..., because it still only count the call to the method you're **in**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use coverage tools? (I would recommend [dotCover](http://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/))

Tool can generate reports in `xml`, `json`, etc, so that you can easily parse them and use results for further calculations.

Comment: Can this be called programmatically? (Without the UI?)

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no SDK currently, but, you can call dotCover process programmatically without problems

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a test coverage tool. It will show what methods of tested assemblies were called. VisualStudio has one built in.

Comment: One thing I want to do is to get this information programmatically, so I can use this information for further calculations. Is this possible?

Comment: Test coverage tool will do a lot of calculations for you, providing useful reports. If you really want to intercept method calls in whole application(to count number of calls), you can do it using Profiling API of CLR. But you may need to write a lot of code for that.